# Android studio display

Tags: android, android-studio

After almost a week without launching Android Studio, I come tonight to continue an application I'm working on and when I open it I notice that the display characters of the IDE have completely changed as you can see on the image. I thought that the language had changed, so I have been on several forums to find out if it is possible to change the language but apparently it is not possible. Given the arrangement of characters I suspected that it did not correspond to a language but I wanted to be sure. I have also tried to launch other IDEs such as NetBeans to make sure that the problem is not coming from my machine and it is working properly. So I come to you to know if someone would have a solution for me, I do not want to be forced to reinstall the IDE at the risk of losing all the update and plugin I installed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing away with the custom Android Studio Theme you're using ?

Comment: No I have not tried this possibility, so I do and I sign you the result

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed it was the problem